# How to do a validation test on Validator in Razor Page Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration-testing, razor-pages, xunit

I'm trying to get started with a tests for FoodValidator. I need help with understanding what this this.factory is and what factory.Services.GetService(); is doing. And some example  to show how test should be done.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;

namespace Food.Project.Tests
{
    public class WebApplicationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory;

        public WebApplicationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            this.factory = factory;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void IFoodItemValidatorTests()
        {
            // itemValidator will be null if it is not registered in the DI container
            var itemValidator = factory.Services.GetService<IFoodItemValidator>();
  
            Assert.NotNull(itemValidator);
        }
    }
}
```

FoodValidator.cs

```
public class FoodItemValidator : IFoodItemValidator
    {

        private List<string> errors { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        public string[] IsValid(FoodItem foodItem)
        {

        
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foodItem.Name))
            {
                errors.Add("Name should contain a value and not a space.");

            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foodItem.Description))
            {
                errors.Add(" Description should contain a value and not a space.");
            }

            if (foodItem.Price <= 0)
            {
                errors.Add("Price should be greater than 0.\n ");
            }
            return errors.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And IFoodItemValidator:

```
namespace Food.Project
{
    public interface IFoodItemValidator
    {
        string[] IsValid(FoodItem foodItem);
    }
}
```

Validator should check that the name and description of an item are not null and not whitespace. Number should be greater then 0.

```
public class FoodItem
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int CookTime { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Have you read the official documentation on Integration testing from Microsoft?. There is a good explanation what the WebApplicationFactory is doing.

Comment: @Marco yes, but i find it difficult due to my language knowledge